# How to pass an int value to JButton actionlistener?

Tags: java, swing, arguments, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm making a quiz program that asks the user simple math questions, recieves an answer, calculates the user's score, etc...

I'm getting an error because I'm using a variable (in this case, x) inside an actionListener:

```
for(x = 0;x < total;x++){
System.out.print((x+1)+". ");

questionLabel.setText(number1" + "+ number2);

answerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int returnedAns = Integer.parseInt(answerTextField.getText());

                if(returnedAns == answerToTheQuestion){
                    score++;
                    System.out.println("correct");
                    question[x].result = true;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("wrong");
                    question[x].result = false;
                }

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
        });
    }
```

when i run my code, it highlights int x and says 'local variables referenced from an inner clas must be final or effectively final'.

Please help me out I really don't know what to dowhat to do.

I can't mark it as final as I need to be able to change it for the for loop to work...

Comment: Make the variable `final` :)

Comment: but the thing is i need to change it....its the loop variable

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to define an extra class for this ActionListener implementation.

```
public class NumberedActionListener implements ActionListener {

  private int number;

  public NumberedActionListener(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you can pass an int value to the constructor.

```
answerButton.addActionListener(new NumberedActionListener(x));
```

This also looks much better  if you like clean code...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of `x` to another variable inside the `for`-loop and then make that variable final.

```
for(x = 0;x < total;x++){
   final int index = x;
   // use index inside your actionListener
}
```